# How to draw a sample from a categorical distribution

Tags: numpy, vectorization, probability

I have a 3D numpy array with the probabilities of each category in the last dimension. Something like:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax

array = np.random.normal(size=(10, 100, 5))
probabilities = softmax(array, axis=2)
```

How can I sample from a categorical distribution with those probabilities?

EDIT:
Right now I'm doing it like this:

```py
def categorical(x):
    return np.random.multinomial(1, pvals=x)

samples = np.apply_along_axis(categorical, axis=2, arr=probabilities)
```

But it's very slow so I want to know if there's a way to vectorize this operation.

Comment: Could you clarify *"probabilities of each category in the last dimension."*? Are there 5 categories and each of the 1000 points have a different probability distirbution?

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys It's for a recommender system  `probabilities[i, j, k]` is the probability that user i rated item j with the rating k

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drawing samples from a given probability distribution is done by building the evaluating the inverse cumulative distribution for a random number in the range 0 to 1. For a small number of discrete categories - like in the question - you can find the inverse using a linear search:

```
## Alternative test dataset
probabilities[:, :, :] = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1])

n1, n2, m = probabilities.shape

cum_prob = np.cumsum(probabilities, axis=-1) # shape (n1, n2, m)
r = np.random.uniform(size=(n1, n2, 1))

# argmax finds the index of the first True value in the last axis.
samples = np.argmax(cum_prob > r, axis=-1)

print('Statistics:')
print(np.histogram(samples, bins=np.arange(m+1)-0.5)[0]/(n1*n2))
```

For the test dataset, a typical test output was:

```
Statistics:
[0.0998 0.4967 0.1513 0.1498 0.1024]
```

which looks OK.

If you have many, many categories (thousands), it's probably better to do a bisection search using a numba compiled function.

Comment: Can't you just use `np.random-choice` and use the `p` argument? Seems both easier to understand and faster.

Comment: @vidstige if you want to convert your comment into an answer, I am happy to upvote. Of course, the manual cdf way works too but a non-liner is always appreciated :smile

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `np.random.choice` function. It has a convenient `p` argument allowing you to specify the probability of each category. See working example below

```
import numpy as np
categories = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']
probabilities = [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]

# draw 1000 samples
n = 1000
draw = np.random.choice(categories, n, p=probabilities)

# print counts to verify
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(draw))
```