# Vectorize sampling from a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, random, vectorization, probability

I have a numpy array of shape `D x N x K`.

I need a resulting `D x N` array of random elements out of K classes, where for each index `[d, n]` there is a different probability vector for the classes, indicated by the third axis.

The [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) for `np.random.choice` only allows 1D array for probabilities.

Can I vectorize this type of sampling, or do I have to use a for loop as follows:

```
# input_array of shape (D, N, K)
# output_array of shape (D, N)

for d in range(input_array.shape[0]):
    for n in range(input_array.shape[1]):
        probabilities = input_array[d, n]
        element = np.random.choice(K, p=probabilities)
        output_array[d, n] = element
```

I would have loved if there is a function such as

```
output_array = np.random.choice(input_array, K, probability_axis=-1)
```

Edit: Managed to find a "hand engineered" solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861868/how-to-draw-a-sample-from-a-categorical-distribution).

Comment: `rng.choice` allows for an `axis` parameter, but `p` still has to be 1d.  So for nd array, it's like doing a choice on a `arange` and using that as index.

Comment: Thanks, but found a somewhat hand engineered solution. See edit.

Comment: Beat me to it. I still think that my solution is marginally simpler though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) nor [`np.random.default_rng().choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) support broadcasting of probabilities in the way that you intend. However, you can cobble together something that works similarly using [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
sprob = input_array.cumsum(axis=-1, dtype=float)
sprob /= sprob[:, :, -1:]
output_array = (np.random.rand(D, N, 1) > sprob).argmin(-1)
```

Unfortunately, [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) does not support multi-dimensional lookup either (probably for related reasons).